# How does `tf.keras.layers.ActivityRegularization` work and how to use it correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

In training of deep neural network, how can [`tf.keras.layers.ActivityRegularization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ActivityRegularization) be used to regularize output?

In my code, `output` have very large value. So I tried to regularize it. So for my last dense layers, I tried:

```
output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout_dense1,
                        units=NUM_OUTPUTS,
                        kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer,
                        activity_regularizer = tf.keras.layers.ActivityRegularization())
```

But no regularization effect is observed in `output` (still very large). I tried all kinds of combination of parameters (default is `tf.keras.layers.ActivityRegularization(L1=0, L2=0)`), but it seems that it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: seems you are combining tf.layers and tf.keras.layers, is this on purpose?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I did this because there is no such things as `tf.layers.ActivityRegularization`. So I thought I can use `tf.layers.` and `tf.keras.layers` interchangeably... Would it matter?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think the proper method should be like this.
(Tensorflow version >= 2)

```
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=NUM_OUTPUTS,
                           kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0., stddev=1.),
                           activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.01))(dropout_dense1)
```

You can change the method, for example, from L2 to L1, or if you want to calculate regularizers your own way.
You can customize it yourself. Please see an example here.

[Tensorflow 2 Developing new regularizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/Regularizer)

but if you want to use **tf.keras.layers.ActivityRegularization**
you can use as follows

```
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=NUM_OUTPUTS)(dropout_dense1)
output_reg = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(output)

# Define ActivityRegularization layer
reg_output = tf.keras.layers.ActivityRegularization(l1=0.001, l2=0.001)

# Apply ActivityRegularization layer to the non-weight directly layer that you want 
output_reg = reg_output(output_reg)

other_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=NUM)(output_reg)
final_output = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(other_layer)

model = tf.keras.Model(input, final_output)
```